# npm run build fails with: Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined

Tags: firebase, vue.js, npm

I´m currently working on a website using vue/cli 4.5.13 and firebase.

After trying to get a simple authentification site working, my npm run build fails with this message:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error
>
> > Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined
>
> You may use special comments to disable some warnings. Use //
> eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line. Use /*
> eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file. ERROR  Build
> failed with errors.

I know this problem was asked here frequently but all the given solutions didn´t work for me.
So far i tried: npm install typescript@latest, npm uninstall @vue/component-compiler-utils,
npm install --dev @vue/component-compiler-utils@3.1.2, npm update vue-template-compiler and npm audit fix (--force).

my package.json looks like this:

```
      "name": "my-website",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@vue/component-compiler-utils": "^3.1.2",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "typescript": "^4.3.2",
        "vue": "^3.0.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.3",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.2",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
          "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
          "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
          "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
          "parser": "babel-eslint"
        },
        "rules": {}
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete node modules directory and then run

```
npm install
```

Comment: Do you have any other package in your project? Try run this one cache could be the problem `npm cache clear --force`

Comment: it kinda worked for now, i can now run build and run serve but the site ist blank and doesn´t show the home screen but i think thats more a routing problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! If you found this answer correct, could you mark it as valid? so any other people facing the same issue can solve it! Thanks in  advance!